# Notepad++: Creating a macro replacing selected text

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, macros

I need a Notepad++ macro that will perform *search and replace*, but for the portion of text that is highlighted at the moment of running the macro.

I tried recording a macro, but it records for the portion of text I had hightlighted at the moment of recording a macro. That's not what I want. I need to apply the *search and replace* for a different text every time I run the macro.

After recording a macro, in `AppData\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml` appears this thing:

```xml
<Macro name="SaR_macro" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="yes" Key="89">
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="some text" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
```

Maybe there's a way to insert something like "current selection" in the place of `some text` in the above? Is that how I should do it?

**EDIT**:

More precisely what I'm trying to accomplish. Let's say I have a txt file looking like that:

```
text text text text text - qwerty
text text text text - asdf
text text text text text text - zxc
```

And the situation I want to achieve is: I select  `- qwerty`, then I press a macro hotkey and as the result I have the  `- qwerty` changed into something else. Then I select  `- asdf`, next I press a macro hotkey and as the result I have the  `- asdf` changed into the same thing as previously. Next, the same thing goes with  `- zxc`.

Comment: There is a way to apply “Find & Replace” only in current selection in the “Find & Replace” dialog box. Could you show an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Toto Edited my question to make it more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that is not possible with a single hotkey.

Nevertheless there is an alternative:

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

- Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)
- Copy this code and save the file (for example replace_highlight.py):

```python
editor.replaceSel('new text')
```

- Goto Plugins >> PythonScript >> Configuration
- Select the script replace_highlight.py
- Save
- Restart Notepad++ (a PythonScript icon will appear in the toolbar)
- Open the file you want to modify
- Highlight the text you want to replace
- Click on the icon previously created
- Done

---

If you want to replace **all occurrences** of the selected text, use the following code:

```
editor.replace(editor.getSelText(), 'NEW TEXT')
```

Comment: Okay, I'm very sorry for still being imprecise there, I really didn't think of it. Your solution replaces only the exact portion I selected (so it has an effect identical to pressing delete). What I want is to replace all the portions of text identical to the selected one in the whole file, just like with the "search and replace" tool.

Comment: @Krz: See my edit.

Comment: Thank you, very useful. And if you want to re-use the selected text, use `oldname = editor.getSelText()` or similar to get the string. See https://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/scintilla.html (or local copy)

Comment: PS: to use a shortcut, you can assign  in `Settings/Shortcut mapper/Plugin commands/Run Previous Script (PythonScript.dll)` to a key combo. Then you have to execute it once manually and can use the combo afterwards.